# ABNewPersonViewController imagePicker orientation and crash issue

Tags: ios, ios6, abaddressbook

My iPad app supports only landscape orientation. I have presented ABNewPersonViewController (in navigationcontroller as apple docs suggestion) modally and is in land scape.

Now,

1. when I am trying to "add Photo" the imagePicker is presented modally in PORTRAIT against my requirement.
2. Then, immediately after adding a Photo, tapping on the image shows a popover with three buttons (- choose photo, edit photo, delete photo).

> Clicking the first two buttons crashes my app with following error
>   message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <ABActionSheet: 0x9bbfde0; baseClass = UIActionSheet; frame = (0 0; 272 156); opaque = NO; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0xaa73d30>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x9bd0370>> is associated with <_UIActionSheetHostingController: 0x9bb1000>. Clear this association before associating this view with <_UIActionSheetHostingController: 0xaa7a610>.'
```

Any Solutions for one and two ?
Thanks & regards
auk

Comment: ABNewPersonViewController *newpersonVC=[[ABNewPersonViewController alloc]init];
    newpersonVC.newPersonViewDelegate=self;
   UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:newpersonVC];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:Nil];

Answer (score 1):

The Exception clearly states that

`"'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! "`

You Are presenting a **UIViewController** with that presenting again a **UIPopOverController** . After clicking at index of the button trieng to present the controller , It's not possible .'

Try with  `dismissViewController`  method according to your stuff.

Comment: It is understood. but we dont have the access to the popover

Answer (score 0):

[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet]; fixed my issue